# What Django model field do I use for a checkbox form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I created an HTML form and am now hooking it up to Django. (I know I should have used Django to create the form, but in this case I didn't). In my models.py, I use CharField for textboxes, CharField with choices for select forms, but for checkboxes, what model field do I use? Do I have to create another class for all of the checkbox choices and then link that with a manytomany relationship? Thank you.

Comment: It entirely depends on what values you want to store for the checkboxes.

Comment: Checkboxes vs. other inputs is a widget level distinction, not form field level.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a [`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield):

> A true/false field.
>
> The default form widget for this field is a [`CheckboxInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxInput).
>
> If you need to accept [`null`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null) values then use [`NullBooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.NullBooleanField) instead.
>
> The default value of `BooleanField` is None when [`Field.default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default) isn’t defined.

The [model field reference page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/) is a good place to find these types of answers.

I've found it helpful to think about my model rather than about HTML forms; if you choose fields based on what your model should have your forms usually work themselves out.

Comment: Or a `ChoiceField` of some sort, totally depends on what the field is.

Comment: Yes. I said "probably", referenced the documentation that clearly explains what a `BooleanField` is, and suggested thinking in terms of models instead of forms. Hopefully that was clear.

Comment: There are 10 checkboxes. Users can check however many they want (or none at all). Are you saying that, in the HTML, I should name each checkbox something distinct and then create 10 BooleanFields in my models.py? Just want to confirm. Thanks.

Comment: @henrich, Peter and Daniel are correct in that the HTML form widget and the model field are separate things. I have suggested in my answer that you think about your _model_ rather than  your _form_. Without knowing what your "10 checkboxes" represent and how they relate to the rest of your model it's impossible to give a complete answer. In many, but certainly not all, cases a `BooleanField` might make sense.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Possible to realize as BooleanField with default options True or False. False gives unchecked box, e.g.:

```
selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I don't know if you can do that in the models, but you can use it in forms read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#setting-arguments-for-widgets) for more information

```
FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = (
    ('blue', 'Blue'),
    ('green', 'Green'),
    ('black', 'Black'),
)

class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    required=False,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,
    )
```